# Local Notifications in iOS without running the app

Tags: ios, swift

My application needs to have more than 10 local notifications at different time (not recurring) on daily basis. According to [iOS official docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html), i can only schedule  64 notifications. I have tried solutions from [this](http:///www.raywenderlich.com) and several others articles on the web but found no working solution.

Is there any way i can schedule the Local notifications at different times even if my app is not running for several days (or killed)?

Comment: you probably need to use a server for your push rather than local notifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way For doing this.

If you want to do it anyhow(not proper solution, just a patch), then just go via following way.

- wake up the app in background - which can be done by using starting location manager, which will wake up your app in background when location get updated, at that time you can do whatever you like with local notification or any other things.

Before applying this method - make sure that - this is too much battery consuming way + not proper way. Your app might get rejected from apple if it is using too much battery.

Read following details(copied from other question from stackoverflow):

An app can be woken by a significant location change, if the app has indicated that it wants to monitor such events.

See: [CLLocationManager Docs][1]

Look for a method called `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`. If a significant location change occurs while your app is not in the foreground or isn't running at all, your application will be launched in the background, allowing the app to perform background-only operations (e.g. no view code will run).

Comment: Background fetch is probably better than using location. For location you will need to get user permission and the app will be rejected if it doesn't actually use location.

Comment: I have also used background fetch but still no success

Answer (score 0):

When you want your app to work in background even when it is killed then you have to enable '**Background Modes**' from your Project's Capabilities and fire your Local Notifications method with specific times through that.

Here is a little code snippet to get you started:

```
var backgroundTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid

override  public func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.reinstateBackgroundTask), name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)

}

 //MARK: Background Task / Local Notifications / Checkin

deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

func reinstateBackgroundTask() {
    if backgroundTask == UIBackgroundTaskInvalid {
        registerBackgroundTask()
    }
}

func registerBackgroundTask() {
    backgroundTask = UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler {
        [unowned self] in
        self.endBackgroundTask()
    }
    assert(backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
}

func endBackgroundTask() {
    NSLog("Background task ended.")
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(backgroundTask)
    backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
}


func dosomething() {

 registerBackgroundTask()

 //Fire Local Notifications accordingly…
 //Use NSTimer if you want it with specific time intervals
}
```

Have a look at this wonderful [Raywenderlich Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios) about Background Modes in iOS.

[Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Comment: That will only give you 3 minutes elapsed before the app will be terminated

Comment: Nope. According to Apple Documentation, It depends what kind of task you want to execute in the background, either you want to play an audio, download content, or run finite length tasks. This adds special entitlement in your Info.plist when you enable 'Background Modes'. So its kinda marked that these apps will use this exclusive feature (even if they are killed) so the OS will be more lenient towards its memory consumption and won't suspend it :)

Comment: Yes, you can use those background tasks to get relaunched, but you only have a few seconds. The use of `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` gives you more time, but only up to 3 minutes. If you test under the debugger then your app won't be killed after the 3 minutes is up (`backgroundTimeRemaining` will just continue to report 0) but if you are running normally, not connected to Xcode then the app will be killed if it exceeds the allowed background time.

Comment: Refer to the documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: Also note "You should not use this method simply to keep your app running after it moves to the background"

Comment: My problem is  that  i want to schedule notifications even if user does not open the app after using it once and i don't think  that background task will solve my problem . I have use background fetch but still no success . I can use background location service but its battery consuming and a bad practice too and please correct me if i am wrong as i have started iOS development just 2 months ago